# Disable renewal process after automatic retries failed

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am using woocommerece subscriptions plugin but i am facing a problem, I need to disable the renewal process when all of my retry rules fail, I need to do this because the plugin has a default renewal email that is sent to the customer after the retries fail and that default behaviour tries to change the subscription status to on hold while my rules define that subscription status will be cancelled on the last attempt so it throws an error that the subscription cannot be changed to on hold

```
function pf_custom_retry_rules( $default_retry_class ) {
    return array(
        array(
            'retry_after_interval'            =>  60,
            'email_template_customer'         => 'WCS_Email_Customer_Payment_Retry',
            'email_template_admin'            => 'WCS_Email_Payment_Retry',
            'status_to_apply_to_order'        => 'pending',
            'status_to_apply_to_subscription' => 'on-hold',
        ),
        array(
            'retry_after_interval'            => 120,
            'email_template_customer'         => 'WCS_Email_Customer_Payment_Retry',
            'email_template_admin'            => 'WCS_Email_Payment_Retry',
            'status_to_apply_to_order'        => 'pending',
            'status_to_apply_to_subscription' => 'on-hold',
        ),
        array(
            'retry_after_interval'            => 180,
            'email_template_customer'         => 'WCS_Email_Customer_Payment_Retry',
            'email_template_admin'            => 'WCS_Email_Payment_Retry',
            'status_to_apply_to_order'        => 'pending',
            'status_to_apply_to_subscription' => 'on-hold',
        ),
        array(
            'retry_after_interval'            => 240,
            'email_template_customer'         => 'WCS_Email_Customer_Payment_Retry',
            'email_template_admin'            => 'WCS_Email_Payment_Retry',
            'status_to_apply_to_order'        => 'pending',
            'status_to_apply_to_subscription' => 'on-hold',
        ),
        array(
            'retry_after_interval'            => 300,
            'email_template_customer'         => 'WCS_Email_Customer_Payment_Retry',
            'email_template_admin'            => 'WCS_Email_Payment_Retry',
            'status_to_apply_to_order'        => 'failed', // Set the status to 'failed'
            'status_to_apply_to_subscription' => 'cancelled', // Set the status to 'cancelled'
        ),
    );
}
add_filter( 'wcs_default_retry_rules', 'pf_custom_retry_rules' );
```

These are my custom rules, i am using these for testing, can anyone help me with this

I have tried to find some hook that could work with this but i am having no luck in finding it

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting the same problem. I am trying to apply the rule that after 3 days of payment retries, it should cancel the subscription.
Following is my code

```
function eg_my_custom_retry_rules( $default_retry_rules_array ) {
return array(
    array(
        'retry_after_interval'            => 86400,
        'email_template_customer'         => 'WCS_Email_Customer_Payment_Retry',
        'email_template_admin'            => 'WCS_Email_Payment_Retry',
        'status_to_apply_to_order'        => 'pending',
        'status_to_apply_to_subscription' => 'active',
    ),
    array(
        'retry_after_interval'            => 86400*2,
        'email_template_customer'         => 'WCS_Email_Customer_Payment_Retry',
        'email_template_admin'            => 'WCS_Email_Payment_Retry',
        'status_to_apply_to_order'        => 'pending',
        'status_to_apply_to_subscription' => 'active',
    ),
    array(
        'retry_after_interval'            => 86400*3,
        'email_template_customer'         => 'WCS_Email_Customer_Payment_Retry',
        'email_template_admin'            => 'WCS_Email_Payment_Retry',
        'status_to_apply_to_order'        => 'failed',
        'status_to_apply_to_subscription' => 'cancelled',
    ),
  );
}add_filter( 'wcs_default_retry_rules', 'eg_my_custom_retry_rules' );
```